# what file is showing at http://localhost/?

Tags: iis, localhost

I am using windows server 2012R2 IIS
I have the Default Web Site set up with Physical path c:\inetpub\wwwroot with pass-through authentication and a classic application pool.

When I browse to show local host I see an old copy of my index.htm  but I can no longer find it on disk.

The order of my default documents is
index.aspx
index.htm
default.aspx

I have tried iisreset and also a reboot.

If I refresh the page then the correct page loads, but why is the old one displaying first?

Answer (score 0):

clear explorer cache

Tools -> Internet Options - > Delete History